# Scrolling through many Azure Key Vault Secrets

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

My employer uses Azure Key Vaults in our multitenant offering. The design chosen leads to many Secrets in the vault making navigating and editing the Secrets painful due to no pagination, forcing support staff to scroll through pages and pages of Secrets. Does anyone else have this problem? Is there another solution to this besides scrolling forever?

Answer (score 1):

You can also manage it using powershell / azure cli:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-powershell#adding-a-secret-to-key-vault

Comment: This is the correct answer.  You have to roll your own solution to manage many secrets.